# Java 8: DecimalFormat with HALF_UP rounding mode

Tags: java, rounding, decimalformat

The following test fails:

```java
@Test
public void testRound() throws Exception {
    double v = 0.015d;
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
    format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    assertEquals("0.02", format.format(v));
}
```

I see that there are resolved issues for [Java 7](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7131459) and [Java 8](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8062756), but it still doesn't work for me on "jdk1.8.0_144":

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: null 
Expected :0.02
Actual   :0.01
```

Comment: 0.015 cannot be exatly represented as a floating point number. It happens the nearest possible representation is slightly less and therefore is rounded down.

Comment: Doubles and floats can't represent 0.015 exactly. Don't use double; instead use BigDecimal right from the start.

Comment: So, is it a normal behaviour? it's not a bug in Java 8, is it?

Comment: Yes, quite normal and not a bug. It's the way floating point arithmetic works.

Comment: However why will "double v = 5.5d;" be rounded as "6"? I.e. correctly?

Comment: Because 5.5 **can** be exactly represented. There are also unrepresentable examples with nearest values slightly larger, they will also be rounded up.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Why are you testing the platform?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.###", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
```

Comment: I need the correctly rounded format "#.##".

Comment: It won't work with 2 deceimal points as you'll get 0.01 which round_up will round to 0.01 that's why it won't work for you correctly.